# Javascript causing mobile navigation to require a 'double tap for links to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I've noticed on the mobile version (iOS) of my website that the main navigation requires links to be tapped twice for the page to redirect. After removing various styles/bits of code I found the cause of the problem, it's my Javascript for a 'sliding line' hover effect.

My basic understanding would be that as the script is still running on mobile, when it's not really needed, it means the navigation is running/expecting a hover effect and once that's run you can then click a link as you intend?

The script works perfect on desktop, so I don't want to change any of the functionality but is there something I can add to prevent this bug on mobile devices? Alternatively, would a javascript 'media query' type thing, stopping the script from running below 1000px be a better solution? If so what would be the best way to implement that?

Thank in advance!

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/moy/pen/pZdjMX

```js
$(function() {
  var $el,
    leftPos,
    newWidth,
    $mainNav = $(".site-nav__list");

  $mainNav.append("<div class='site-nav__line'></div>");
  var $magicLine = $(".site-nav__line"),
    $currentMenu = $(".current-menu-item");

  $magicLine
    .width($currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.width() : 0)
    .css("left", $currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.find("a").position().left : 0)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

  var hoverOut;

  $(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
      clearTimeout(hoverOut);

      $el = $(this);
      leftPos = $el.position().left;
      newWidth = $el.parent().width();

      if (!$magicLine.width()) {
        $magicLine.stop().hide().css({
          left: leftPos,
          width: newWidth
        }).fadeIn(100);
      } else {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
          opacity: 1,
          left: leftPos,
          width: newWidth
        });
      }
    },
    function() {
      hoverOut = setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$currentMenu.length) {
          $magicLine.fadeOut(100, function() {
            $magicLine.css({
              left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
              width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
            });
          });
        } else {
          $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
          });
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
/* Header */

.page-head {
  background: white;
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-head__logo {
  background-image: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  width: 200px;
}


/* Nav */

.site-nav {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

.site-nav__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.site-nav__list li {
  background: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.site-nav__list a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  transition: color .15s;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.site-nav__list a {
  color: red;
}

/* Underline */

.site-nav__line {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header class="page-head">

      <a href="#" class="page-head__logo">Logo Here </a>

      <nav class="site-nav ">
          <ul class="site-nav__list">
            <li class="site-nav__item "><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Looooonger Title</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Company</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Login</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link amp">Apply</a></li>
          </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the cause of the problem is running that script on mobile screens, you can call sliding script only on desktops with this code:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 739) {      
//Desktop scripts
} 
else {
  //mobile scripts
}
```

You can change the screen width of devices you want to script work on them by changing `739`. After that your script will run only on screens larger that 739px or what you've choose.

**Update**

If you want to everything works correct after resizing, You should do a little trick.

Personally, I use this method because it's the only way that makes you sure about bugs and problems. The trick is reloading the page after resizing.
It's not costly in many cases because most of the things cashed and don't need to redownloading. There are lots of methods to do that, but I use the below one because it works good and is simple and short:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    location = location;
}
```

You just need to add this lines at the end of your script file. After resizing, everything will work well again.

**How it works?**

When you resize the window, a javascript event will emit. What we done in the last code is overriding the event listener of that event. So when the user resize the window, the `location = location;` code will execute.

What this line means? the location object is a property of `window` object and keeping information about current window url. When you change the `location` of a `window`, browser page will reload to getting the new `window` of the new `location` ([more info about location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)).

What we done here is assigning current `location` to the `location`. So browser thinks we had a redirect request and reloads the page. But because the new `location` is the same object as previous one, the page will reload instead of redirecting to somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it works! Is it possible to amend so it checks on resize? I know it only affects mobile devices so people won't be resizing the browser but just thinking is a tablet was changed from portrait to landscape?

Comment: I added that for you in the answer. If it was useful you can accept it as correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out in a bit. I'm not sure I understand how the new code relates to the previous `if ( $(window).width() > 739) {}` code. What does `location = location;` do?

Comment: I've added more details about the code. hope it helps you.

Comment: Ah ok cool, that works well. My only concern would be that if the user scrolled and then rotated the device the page would then refresh and they'd need to scroll all the way down the page again. A bit of a fringe case! But I'll have a play around with it in a bit. Thanks again! :)

Comment: As far as I know, some browsers consider the scrolled height, But I'm not sure. You should test it.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is you to double click it before redirecting to its page, Try thi

```
$('.site-nav__list a').click(function(){
$(this).click();
```

});

the function is when you click the navigation the script will click it again,

Comment: Does that essentially fire a double click? Just wondering how that'll affect the desktop script?

Comment: yeah, I use that script when I need to hard refresh another page, an example is when your script on about us page won't work unless you reload the page. it also affects both mobile and desktop, but don't affect any script.